# Positive definite kernel vs. positive definite function

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, definition

What is the difference between positive definite kernels and positive definite functions?  As I understand it, a positive definite kernel is a positive definite function if it is translation invariant.  Is this correct?  If not, what is the actual relationship between these concepts?  I'm reading Learning with Kernels and using this text, Wikipedia, and Google, haven't been able to find a good answer to this question.

References are appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a good characterization of a positive matrix $[a_{j,k}]$ except as one for which $\sum_{j}\sum_{k}a_{j,k}x_{j}\overline{x_{k}} \ge 0$ for all $[x_{j}]\in \mathbb{C}^{n}$?

Comment: This is the only characterization that I'm aware of, looking back over the material again, I couldn't find mention of anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Wendland's Scattered Data Approximation covers this topic in chapter 6. Below, I have paraphrased relevant definitions.

**Definition 6.1** A continuous **function** $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called positive definite on $\mathbb{R}^d$ if for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, all pairwise distinct $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, and all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^N\backslash\{0\}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j=1}^N 
\sum_{k=1}^N 
\alpha_j
\bar{\alpha_k}
\Phi(x_j - x_k)
>0
\end{equation*}

**Definition 6.24** A continuous **kernel** $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called positive definite on $\mathbb{R}^d$ if for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, all pairwise distinct $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_N\}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, and all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}^N\backslash\{0\}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j=1}^N 
\sum_{k=1}^N 
\alpha_j
\bar{\alpha_k}
\Phi(x_j,x_k)
>0
\end{equation*}

To answer the posed question, functions are basically translation invariant kernels.

Suppose $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is translation invariant, i.e. $\Phi(x-t,y-t)=\Phi(x,y)$ for all $t,x,y$. Then $\Phi(x,y)=\Phi(x-y,0)$, so $\Phi$ is completely determined by $\Phi(z,0)$ for $z\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Hence, we can view it as a function on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Conversely, every function gives rise to a kernel that is translation invariant.